# Changing the orientation (portrait or landscape) of an Excel chart using VBA

Tags: vba, layout, graph, charts, excel

I am trying to write a macro to automatically print all the charts I have created in a workbook using another macro. (literally hundreds) The problem I'm having is that I cannot figure out how to change the graph from a portrait layout to a landscape layout using VBA. I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I tried the code bellow but it gives me an error at the line " .ChartObjects(x).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape " I understand that for a chart object that this isn't the correct property but I can't figure out what else it is.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Print_All_Charts()
    Dim szASheet As String
    szASheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    Dim lChartObjCount As Long
    lChartObjCount = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False

        .ActivePrinter = "HP Color LaserJet 5550 PS on Ne08:"

        'On Error Resume Next
        Dim wks As Worksheet
        For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

            Dim x As Long
            For x = 1 To lChartObjCount

                With wks

                    .ChartObjects(x).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

                    .ChartObjects(x).Select

                    .ChartObjects(x).Activate

                    .PrintOut , , 1

                End With

            Next x

        Next wks

        ActiveChart.Deselect
        With Sheets(szASheet)
            .Select
            .Range("A1").Select
        End With

        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Charts are not really my area of expertise.  However, as I understand them, they are not "orientated".  The height may be less than the width but that is not the same.  What effect does `Sheets("xxxxxx").PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape` have?

Comment: Other points. (1) You should have `End With` underneath `.ActivePrinter = ...` to terminate `With Application`.  Add another `With Application` before the final `.ScreenUpdating = True`. (2) You set `lChartObjCount` to the number of charts on the page which is active when the macro is started.  You then use `lChartObjCount` for every sheet in the workbook.  You need to have `With wks` `For x = 1 To .ChartObjects.Count`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Manipulating Excel charts using VBA is always a bit confusing, because there are `ChartObject` objects and then there are `Chart` objects. Each `ChartObject` object has a child `Chart` object. It isn't always very intuitive which properties and methods belong to the `Chart` and which are to be found on its parent `ChartObject`. Quoting VBA help:

> [**ChartObject**] represents an embedded chart on a worksheet. The **ChartObject** object acts as a container for a **Chart** object. Properties and methods for the **ChartObject** object control the appearance and size of the embedded chart on the worksheet.

Reading VBA help can drive you nuts if you don't have your glasses on, because `ChartObject` means something different than `Chart` object!

Anyhow, as it turns out, `.PageSetup.Orientation` sits on `Chart` and not `ChartObject` as you were inferring.

```
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim chartObject As ChartObject

    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each chartObject In wks.ChartObjects
            .Chart.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape ' or xlPortrait
            .Chart.PrintOut Preview:=True, ActivePrinter:="PDFCreator"
        Next
    Next
```

This assumes that you want to print each chart on a separate page. What you were doing in your code was printing out each entire worksheet at once, but that doesn't seem to square with the rest of your question.

Here I used PDFCreator as my printer, because I didn't want to waste a bunch of paper while testing this code. You can of course adjust this as you see fit.

Also I set the active printer at the time of printing. Of course you can also use `Application.ActivePrinter` instead, but that will affect the active printer even when the macro is done running.

Comment: Works great! All I had to do was insert the child object after my chartobject so code looks like this, " ChartObjects(x).Chart.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape " Thanks For your help Jean! The confusion between Parent and child objects drives me crazy. The code now works great to print out every chart in a workbook in a landscape layout!